# Using Handler class

Tags: asp.net, session, httphandler

> i have written following in the handler class to check the session
>   satate.

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Session["UserID"] == null || context.Session["ClientCode"] == null || context.Session["UserType"] == null)
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("~/LogIn.aspx");
            }
        }
```

now i need to make it affect on every .aspx page in my application how can i do it?

Comment: You could put this code in the Global.asax file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll either need an `IHttpModule` for that, or subscribe to `Application.BeginRequest` event somewhere in `Global.asax`. Former is cleaner, but requires changes to `Web.config`, latter is arguably less clean, but it's less code and doesn't require configuration changes.